# Dialog message on Ajax.BeginFrom submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor

I have a form that I want to fill out and in the controller action that is called during form submission do the actual form submission and show a dialog based on whether the form submission was successful or not. Here are the details. The Ajax.BeginForm in the Razor page

```
                @using (Ajax.BeginForm(
                    "EmailFormSubmit",
                    "ContactUsDropdown",
                    new { },
                    new AjaxOptions() {
                    OnBegin = "ajaxBeginEmail",
                    OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccessEmail",
                    OnComplete = "emailFormComplete",
                    OnFailure = "ajaxFailureEmail"
                    },
                    new { 
                        id = "contact-email-form",
                        @class = "webform-client-form"
                    }))
                {
```

When the controller action is called the form data is put together and the "form" is POST'd to the server

```
            var formDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            formDictionary.Add(...);
```

...

```
            var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formDictionary);
            HttpResponseMessage formPostResult = await client.PostAsync(ConfigManager.GetAppSetting("ContactUsUrl"), formData);
            if (formPostResult.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var response = await formPostResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView("_ContactUsDropdownEmailFormError");
            }
```

...

```
        return PartialView("_ContactUsDropdownEmailFormConfirmation");
```

So if there is not an error a simple string representation of the is returned. In this case it is

<div>Thank you!</div>

Then the OnSuccess function is called with the returned text. And a dialog is formed to display the message.

```
    function emailFormComplete(result) {

        $(result.responseText.trim()).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: "auto",
            maxHeight: 1000,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            create: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css("maxWidth", "1000px");
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {
                console.log('confirm dialog open');
            },
            beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                console.log('confirm dialog closing');
            },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                $('#email-form').dialog('close');
                console.log('confirm dialog close');
            }
        });
```

...

The problem is that I get the message that the dialog is opened but I don't see it. I replace the Jquery dialog with an alert and the message is displayed (although it obviously doesn't interpret the HTML). How do I get the dialog to appear? Am I missing something? This is an MVC 5 framework project (not .NET Core).

Comment: Do you have the NuGet package JQuery.UI.Combined installed and bundled?